# Burg Compatibility

Tags: 10.10, grub2, burg

Is burg compatible with Ubuntu 10.10? And if yes, are there any kind of errors that will appear if install it improperly?

Answer (score 4):

I have installed at this very moment with the latest GRUB using the BURG PPA. It works fine on Ubuntu 10.10.

You shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is compatible.